# Java Jackson disable enum keys conditionally

Tags: java, enums, jackson

I'm using Java jackson for dynamic serialization and deserialization to/from json.

I want to have a custom annotation *@JsonDebug*, which will basically turn on/off the serialization of
field etc. depending on a static variable *debugMode*. The idea is that if an enum key is tagged with the annotation,
it shouldn't be useable while serialization/deserialization process is on.

The problem is that the only way I find doing it is by either implementing custom serializer/deserializer for the enum I want, which is not a general solution or by overriding the existing Enum serialization/deserialization process which is kind of a overkill for a single annotation processing. I tried using *AnnotationIntrospector* and override behavior of *hasIgnoreMarker* which is the way it works for fields, but it doesn't ignore enum keys. I thought mixin annotations might be the way to go, but they only  work for specified classes  with specified field names. I found out that even with *ignore* annotations on keys, they still serialize/deserialize to/from json.

---

.